# GridView cells are empty during SelectedIndexChanged when adding a column dynamically.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, page-lifecycle, selectedindexchanged

I'm creating a GridView wrapper class which retrieves certain bits of data from the database and then displays it. When a row is selected then I raise an event which other classes will listen to. I have also made a method which adds a new column to the GridView which some simple icons in it.

Here is some of my code:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    CreateGridView(); // This creates the gridview and sets it properties
    PopulateGridView(); // This queries the DB and binds the data

    AddIconColumn(gvData.HeaderRow); //Add Icon Column to header
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvData.Rows)
    {
        AddIconColumn(row); // Add Icon Column to each row
    }
}

protected virtual void AddIconColumn(GridViewRow row)
{
    if (!ShowIcons) return;

    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        TableHeaderCell HeaderCell = new TableHeaderCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = string.Empty;
        row.Cells.AddAt(index, HeaderCell);
    }

    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var NewCell = new TableCell();
        var SwitchCell = row.Cells[6] as TableCell;
        NewCell.CssClass = columnValueDictionary[SwitchCell.Text];
        row.Cells.AddAt(index, NewCell);
    }
}

public void gvData_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvData.SelectedRow; // Get the selected row

    int selectedID; 
    var id = row.Cells[2].Text; // When the icon column is enabled, all the cells are empty at this point !

    if (int.TryParse(id, out selectedObjID))
    {
        if (SelectedIDChanged != null)
        {
            SelectedIDChanged(this, new SelectedIDChangedEventArgs(selectedObjID));
        }
    }
}
```

When I add the new column with the icons, the GridView's SelectedIndexChanged method can't retrieve any data from the row. All the cells text is empty during the SelectedIndexChanged event. If I dont add the icon row (by setting ShowIcons to false) then the cells have the correct text during the SelectedIndexChanged changed event.

What could be causing this behaviour?